# Write a query to extract information from 4 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database for a science school.

In this school, students enroll in their favorite classes. They pay tuition and may drop out of a class.

This database has a "students" table that contains normal student information, including id. (I will mention only the important fields)

A "class" table containing general class information, including class_id, name, tuition.

There is an interface table called "kelas" to store information id, class_id, student_id, state.

If the student withdraws from the class, the state field changes to 0. In registration, its value is 1.

A table called "payment" also holds payments. Includes id, class_id, student_id, price, time fields

(No relationships defined for tables)
[image]

Now I want to have a query that can give me the following information with a student ID.

1- Details of the classes in which the student has registered with a special ID.

2- Total payment of the desired student in each of the registration classes.

3- The total number of students enrolled in each of the classes mentioned.

4- The number of students who dropped out of each of the mentioned classes.

If you need other information, please let me know so I can answer.

I tried a lot to be able to do this query but every time I had a problem in one section. For example, this query does not work properly:

```
select class.* ,
        sum(DISTINCT payment.price) as sumPay, 
        kelas.state as studentState, kelas.student_id, 
        count(DISTINCT kelas.state) countEnserafiCompliment, 
        sum(kelas.cancelpi) as cancelipayment,
        COUNT(DISTINCT kelas.student_id) as studentNumber 
FROM kelas
    JOIN class ON kelas.class_id = class.class_id
    left JOIN payment ON kelas.class_id = payment.class_id 
        AND kelas.student_id=payment.student_id
WHERE kelas.student_id = 1
GROUP BY kelas.class_id
```

thank you

Comment: The result set you are asking for is not one result set, it is several. In fact each of your four queries is for totally different data. Just write four queries!

Comment: instead of joing the tbale make the queries that produce the result for example sum(DISTINCT payment.price) before joining

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol All results are required in one section. There must be a query to receive all this information

Comment: I did not catch. You may give an example as a query @nbk

Comment: for example instead of payment use `SELECT 
class_id ,
student_id,
sum(DISTINCT payment.price)
FROM 
 payment 
    GROUP BY class_id ,student_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer in a local forum. I will post it here for other friends to use:

```
SELECT
 class.class_id,class.name,class.term,class.state,class.tuition,
 kelas.state as studentState,kelas.student_id AS student_id ,kelas.cancelpi as studentCanceliPi,
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        kelas
    WHERE
        state=1 AND class_id=class.class_id
) as present,
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        kelas
    WHERE
        class_id=class.class_id
) as allStudentNumber,
    (
    SELECT
        SUM(kelas.cancelpi)
    FROM
        kelas
    WHERE
        class_id=class.class_id
    ) AS sumCanceliPi,
(
    SELECT
        SUM(`price`)
    FROM
        payment
    WHERE
        class_id=class.class_id AND student_id = 1
) as total_payment
FROM
 class
INNER JOIN kelas ON kelas.class_id=class.class_id AND kelas.student_id= 1
```